# Sage Theme - JavaScript not showing up in <head>

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, letteringjs

I can't get my JavaScript libraries to show up in my `<head>` tag.
I'm using the Sage Theme, Bower to install JavaScript libraries, and `gulp` to compile files from my asset folder into my `dist` folder.

First, I added a library with Bower:

```
$ bower install letteringjs --save
```

Then I `gulp` to compile my files. At this point everything seems to work fine. The `jquery.lettering.js` makes its way into my `dist/scripts` folder.

**bower.json**:

```
{
  "name": "sage",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/sage/",
  "authors": [
  "Ben Word <ben@benword.com>"
],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#v4.0.0-beta",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
  "letteringjs": "^0.7.0"
 }
}
```

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "main.js": {
      "files": [
        "scripts/**/*",
        "scripts/main.js"
      ],
      "main": true
    },
    "main.css": {
      "files": [
        "styles/main.scss"
      ],
      "main": true
    },
    "customizer.js": {
      "files": [
        "scripts/customizer.js"
      ]
    },
    "jquery.js": {
      "bower": ["jquery"]
    },
    "jquery.lettering.js": {
      "bower": ["letteringjs"]
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "devUrl": "http://localhost:8888/ji/"
  }
}
```

But I still get errors in my console:

[image: screenshot of console error]

The `script src` link isn't showing up in my source code. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and have only made one other site with Sage, so it's still pretty new to me.

Any advice or past experiences are extremely helpful!